# rubystack with existing MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I want to install redmine, so i found convenient to try installing first bitnami RubyStack locally, however i do not want it to use its default mysql server, but i want it to use my already installed mysql instance. In [here](http://bitnami.org/tutorials/from_instantrails_to_rubystack) it mentions that MySQL is installed as a 'service' from the instalation folder, but i'm curious if this means its tinkering with /etc/init.d/ or /etc/mysql folders

Any has used RubyStack with existing mysql db?

Answer (score 0):

When it mentions that MySQL is installed as service it is referring to Windows. Regarding using Redmine module with a different MySQL instance unfortunately it is not supported. However what you could try to do is to install it on top of the RubyStack and then migrate the MySQL data. Once it is installed change the configuration files in Redmine to point them to your existing MySQL installation.